# Link error LNK2005 several CUDA files

Tags: c++, linker, cuda

I got some problems with the error "Link error LNK2005 ... already defined". The files are as follows:

```
// File Bitmap4.cu
#include "Bitmap4.h" // header
#include "Bitmaps_cuda.h" // header with just the definitions of the kernels

..... // I call 3+2 kernel functions (3 in one method, 1 in another and 1 in another one)
```

Then I have this one:

```
// File Bitmap8.cu
#include "Bitmap8.h" // header
#include "Bitmaps_cuda.h" // the same as above

..... // I call 4 kernel functions (4 in the same method)
```

Then I have the kernel header:

```
#ifndef __BITMAPS_KERNEL__
#define __BITMAPS_KERNEL__

......  // 9 kernels definitions

#endif
```

And finally, I have this one:

```
// File Bitmaps_cuda.h
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Inside here there all the kernel functions that the files 
// Bitmap4.cu and Bitmap8.cu are using
```

The problem is that, if i don't include the **#include "Bitmaps_cuda.h"** in one of the Bitmap*.cu, of course, the compiler will say that I missed the definitions of the kernels functions. I read a lot of posts and i already included the "Additional Dipendencies" and the required PATHs. The problems started when I added the file Bitmap8.cu with its relative kernels, because before that, the application was working properly.

Anyway, those are the error that i have:

```
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl big_random_block(int(?big_random_block@@YAPAXH@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "int * __cdecl big_random_block_int(int(?big_random_block_int@@YAPAHH@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "unsigned char __cdecl value(float,float,int(?value@@YAEMMH@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl start_thread(unsigned int(__stdcall*)(void *),void *)" (?start_thread@@YAPAXP6GIPAX@Z0@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl end_thread(void *)"(?end_thread@@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl destroy_thread(void *)"(?destroy_thread@@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl wait_for_threads(void * const *,int)"(?wait_for_threads@@YAXPBQAXH@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl__device_stub__Z14float_to_colorPhPKf(unsigned char *,float const *)"(?__device_stub__Z14float_to_colorPhPKf@@YAXPAEPBM@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl float_to_color(unsigned char *,float_const *)" (?float_to_color@@YAXPAEPBM@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl__device_stub__Z14float_to_colorP6uchar4PKf(struct uchar4 *,float const *)"(?__device_stub__Z14float_to_colorP6uchar4PKf@@YAXPAUuchar4@@PBM@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl float_to_color(struct uchar4 *,float_const *)" (?float_to_color@@YAXPAUuchar4@@PBM@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj

1>C:\Users\dberdin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\gpuSPAM\Debug\gpuSPAM.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I tried different solutions but with any results.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

On the website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f.aspx) i found that one of the causes of those errors is:
*- An absolute is defined twice, with a different value in each definition.*
Well, actually, as i wrote in the bottom, i have these kind of definetions, but i can't do differently. Any idea how to solve it ?

Thank you again in advance

Comment: I included a header file twice! Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors came because i double included a file. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Then I have the kernel header:
>
> #ifndef __BITMAPS_KERNEL__
> #define __BITMAPS_KERNEL__
>
> ......  // 9 kernels definitions
>
> #endif
> ```

Did you mean to say that you have 9 kernel declarations, not definitions?

You can't have the kernel definitions in a header file.

Make sure all your .cu files link to the same runtime (open the Properties sheet on each .cu file and comparing the `CUDA C/C++ | Host | Runtime Library` settings.) Also make sure that is the same runtime as is used by your regular cpp files.

Comment: It is perfectly legal to have kernel definitions in a header, as long as that header gets imported only once, and through the device code compilation trajectory. Template libraries like Thrust do this extensively.

Comment: "It is perfectly legal to have kernel definitions in a header, as long as that header gets imported only once, and through the device code compilation trajectory." True, but do you then really have a header file? It's more like you have an implementation file disguised as a header file, which will cause no end of confusion down the line. Templated kernel definitions would be an exception, agreed.

Comment: Well, the solution of Roger Dahl helped me to fix other problems, but still the compiler is giving me the same errors as i posted above! I can't get it, becuase the problem started when i added more kernels definitions and kernel functions. To be honest, part of the kernel functions are doing the same operations except for some parameters inside, but still, it's weird that i can't compile.

Comment: @DavideBerdin: If you can make your whole project available somewhere, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @DavideBerdin: I don't understand why you accepted an answer and then opened another, almost identical question when this apparently didn't resolve your problem????

Comment: @RogerDahl: thank you for your help, but i solved. Apparently I included a header twice.

Comment: @DavideBerdin: No problem. Please remove the accepted answer from my reply, then create your own reply, move your comment about having included the header file twice into that reply, and accept that as the answer.