# Cuda kernel functions in multiple files

Tags: c++, linker, cuda

I was wondering if it's possible to call the same kernel functions from different .cu files. I mean, my program has different classes and all of them has some common functions, but with different size memory; for example:

```
void Bitmap8::Or(const Bitmap8 &b1, const Bitmap8 &b2);

// the function above is as same as this one (of course they are in two different files)

void Bitmap4::Or(const Bitmap4 &b1, const Bitmap4 &b2);
```

Both of them has different memory size allocation. I created a unique CUDA kernel for them for executing the operations. Is it possible that could be some conflict whereas I'm compiling the program ? because I'm having all the time those kind of errors:

```
1>Bitmap8.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl big_random_block(int)" (?big_random_block@@YAPAXH@Z) already defined in Bitmap4.cu.obj
```

And there are a lot of them

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is big_random_block? Where is it defined? I hope you are not including Bitmap8.cu and Bitmap4.cu in each other?

Comment: I don't know! Actually, that's the point of my question...I can't understand what it means! Inside the kernel function there is just a for loop! Anyway, Bitmpa8.cu and Bitmap4.cu are not included in each other. In this post there is a more explanation of my problem which a different question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011460/link-error-lnk2005-several-cuda-files>

Comment: How about posting some more code. This is impossible to answer as it is. If you cannot accurately describe the structure of *your own code*, how can you expect someone else to diagnose what might be going wrong?

Comment: @talonmies: I already solved. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possibile call the same functions from different files. My errors were related to a double inclusion of an header! Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same function from different files (functions)
You should have though correct parameters.

For example in one file you can #define malloc_size 20 and in another file #define malloc_size 20176
and every time call malloc_size which will be different in each file..

I think you should take a look in your code again and clarify what it does.
start from something simple.

Regards